# Wiremocking delete not happening

Tags: rest, soap, restful-url, wiremock

I am trying to mock a restful delete operation from a https soap service.
the rest call is as follows

```
http://ixyz.elb.amazonaws.com/credit-cards/accounts/B2J1ofVLu%2B%25YTNU8%3D/payments/A%2BohlapfKazCWU8UuxF5I%2Fbf%2FhBFRHB%2B
```

I am using the following to stub the delete

```
stubFor(delete(urlPathMatching("/credit-cards/accounts/~/payments/~"))
                        .willReturn(aResponse()
                            .withStatus(200)));
```

The delete code is below its sample but the actual code is diff

```
HttpEntity <?> entity = new HttpEntity <>(new HttpHeaders());
new RestHelper().exchange(url, HttpMethod.DELETE, entity, String.class);
```

But the call is not getting stubbed with this. I tried using * instead of ~ but still not working.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `.*` for "any characters" rather than `~` in your path regex.

Comment: I used regular exception.. I guess there were some special charachters adding in the path url